# How to deal with a lot of windows?

Tags: gnome

I'm x-windows user and for some reason managing windows was easier for me on windows. on linux I also have consoles. is there any cool tool to help user with managing windows?

Comment: super+d? , send windows to other workspaces?, roll the windows over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many great tools to multi-task and work with many windows built within ubuntu .

You should watch [this video from Jorge Castro](http://castrojo.blip.tv/file/4997614?filename=Castrojo-HowIMultitaskInUnity835.ogv) about multi tasking .

It talks about

- Multi-taking with the launcher
- Alt +Tab
- Workspaces
- Expo

and more .